# Export jagged array from C# into text file or excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, txt

All I need to do is take a jagged array and print the values so I can bring it to excel to make graphs. The array is double integer. I have seen alot of posts on doing the opposite but not on bringing it from C# to a text file.

Comment: Jagged? Do you mean a multidimensional array? Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes. Jagged is the same as multi-dimensional I believe. I have tried to the array into lines of strings but I had no luck with that.

Comment: No a jagged array is not the same as multi-dimensional.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/597720/1070452

Answer (score 0):

Given:
Object[][] myJagged;
string outfileName;

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outfileName);
for(int y = 0; y < myJagged.GetLength(); y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < myJagged[y].GetLength(); x++)
        sw.Write(myJagged[y][x].ToString() + ",");
    sw.WriteLine();
}
sw.Close();
```